# Linux - server has limited number of processes

Tags: linux, bash, process, hosting

I want to change all jpg images to webp. I use linux command like this:

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' | xargs -P 9 -I {} sh -c 'cwebp -q 80 $1 -o $1' _ {} \;
```

However, my server has a limited number of processes (for my user). I got the error "Cannot fork: Resource temporarily unavailable" and the command is interrupted. How can I convert all images? Can I limit the number of processes used for the command, so that it does not stop?

Comment: Don't use the `-P` option to `xargs`. Then it will just run one process at a time.

Comment: Or just reduce `9` to a smaller number. That's the number of parallel processes `xargs` is using.

Comment: Why do you need `|| true`?

Comment: I reduced 9 to a smaller number and it works. Thank you :)
"|| true" was for test, I removed that.